# Kонцепт «хамство» по Вежбицкой / Concept “khamstvo” according to Wierzbicka

Tags: semantics, узус, социолингвистика, психолингвистика

Каково точное значение концепта "хамство" в терминах семантики Вежбицкой?

Опишите, пожалуйста, понятие "хамство", используя "семантические примитивы" из списка ниже. Внизу также дан пример описания другого концепта (Amazement).

- «субстантивы»:

  > я (I), ты (you), кто-то (someone), что-то (something), люди (people)
- «детерминаторы и квантификаторы»:

  > этот (this), тот же самый (the same), другой (other), один (one), два (two), много (many/much), все/весь (all)
- «ментальные предикаты»:

  > думать (о) (think (about)), говорить (say), знать (о) (know (about)), чувствовать (feel), хотеть (want)
- «действия и события»:

  > делать (do), происходить/случаться (happen (to))
- «оценки»:

  > хороший (good), плохой (bad)
- «дескрипторы»:

  > большой (big), маленький (small)
- «время и место»:

  > когда (when), где (where), после/до (after/before), под/над (under/above)
- «метапредикаты»:

  > не/нет/отрицание (по), потому что/из-за (because), если (if/would), мочь (сап)
- «интенсификатор»:

  > очень (very)
- «таксономия и партономия»:

  > вид/разновидность (kind of), часть (part of)
- «нестрогость/прототип»:

  > подобный/как (like).

Пример описания концепта Amazement:

> **Amazement**
>
> X чувствует что-то
>   иногда человек думает примерно так:
>   сейчас что-то произошло
>   до этого я не знал: это может произойти
>   если бы я подумал об этом, я бы сказал: этого не может произойти
>   поэтому этот человек чувствует что-то
>   X чувствует что-то похожее

Список "семантических примитивов" и схема описания взяты из:
Вежбицкая А. *Язык. Культура. Познание.* М.: Pуcские словари, 1996.

Comment: You might want to make this question more interesting to other people if you explain your motivation or a problem that you are trying to solve. As it stands now, the question is about the Russian language and the Russian picture of the world, but I'm afraid many people will find it too theoretical.

Comment: @Olga, I do not mind theoretical, but I agree that the question needs to be formed as a proper question (I still do not know what this here author wants), not as an essay prompt from the upper-division linguistics course.

Comment: The concept description in Wierbicka's paradigm can hardly result in an essay. The concepts are used to provide a brief outline of maximum ten lines or so

Comment: Such an interesting material! I have already started reading Wierzbicka's works, and I wonder if this universal semantical language is applicable, for example, in mathematical linguistics?

Comment: I would use "понятие" instead of "концепт". "Концепт" may be a valid technical term, but it sounds very strange to me.

Comment: Well, you are not me.

Answer (score 3):

Вначале надо определиться с самим смыслом слова "хамство". Обычные определения из словарей, по-моему, не годятся, потому что они построены по методу "сепуление - см. сепульки" (ссылки на "поведение, свойственное хаму" и тому подобное - а как себя ведёт хам? если по-хамски, то круг замкнулся).

Я потерял источник, но однажды видел такое определение (привожу своими словами, может быть, громоздко): "Хамство - открытое действие по дестабилизации эмоциональной сферы собеседника (оппонента) для достижения желаемого результата, который иначе не был бы достигнут или не предполагался". Ключевые моменты - 1) наличие второго участника взаимодействия (или более двух), 2) цель (например, для довлатовской продавщицы - заставить "интеллигента" купить именно то, что она хочет продать, а не качественный товар, и она оскорбляет его, чтобы он не смог добиться своего), 3) действие (как правило, словами, но бывают и варианты физического воздействия), 4) естественное отличие от грубости (кто-то может даже разговаривать матом, но явно не иметь цели оскорбить, просто потому что он иначе не умеет) и от наглости (например, вклиниться в ряд машин, потому что что-то заставляет ехать быстрее - это наглость, но не хамство), с которыми тут сравнивали.

(Я заранее предполагаю возражения против этого определения, что оно неадекватно чьим-то персональным представлениям об обсуждаемом слове. Возможны корректировки отдельных моментов в нём. Но оно по любому лучше рекурсивных определений из обычных словарей, которые ничего не объясняют, а вместо этого апеллируют к эмоциональным понятиям, которые каждый воспринимает по-своему.)

Тогда описание "по Вежбицкой" будет где-то так (я смотрю на пример и делаю аналогично ему):

- X взаимодействует (общается) c Y
- X желает достичь некоей цели
- X предполагает, что "спокойное" общение, рекомендованное моралью, этикой, этикетом и т.д., не даст нужного X'у результата
- X выбирает достижение результата путём эмоциональной дестабилизации Y
- X подбирает метод, который должен привести к такой дестабилизации, согласно тому, что знает про Y
- X применяет этот метод к Y (вероятнее всего, оскорблением, но возможны и другие пути)
- Y, вероятнее всего, теряется (тушуется) и теряет силы для достижения своей цели

Comment: Очень хорошая модель, ставлю +1!  Осталось только перевести на семантические примитивы понятия "общается", "цель","достичь цели", "мораль", "рекомендовать","эмоциональная дестабилизация" итд.

Answer (score 2):

Какое интересное задание! Вежбицку я не читала, но Вы очень понятно объясняете, так что попытаюсь решить проблему.

Хамство = манера поведения, свойственная хаму | конкретный поступок, в котором человек проявил себя как хам.

> Хам
>
> хама, м.
>
> 1. В языке дворян: человек, принадлежащий к низшим классам и
>      лишенный потому всякого человеческого достоинства (презрит,
>      дореволюц.). - Он там дворовых людей по-французски учить выдумал! Это,
>      дескать, ему полезно! Хаму-то, слуге-то! Достоевский.
> 2. перен.
>      Грубый, наглый и невоспитанный человек, готовый на подлости (разг.
>      презрит, бран.). Секретари его все хамы, все продажны, людишки,
>      пишущая тварь, все вышли в знать, все ныне важны. Грибоедов. (По имени
>      Хама, сына библейского Ноя, проклятого отцом за непочтение.)
>
> Толковый словарь Ушакова.

Тогда переходим к составляющим 2-го пункта: грубость, наглость,невоспитанность, подлость. Попробую сразу сконструировать окончательное описание... Явно понадобятся 2 субъекта, потому что эти понятия связаны с оценкой поведения нашего хама обществом (или конкретным его представителем).

**Грубиян**

```
X думает: Y похож на кого-то
иногда человек Z говорит другому (R) очень плохое
из-за этого потом R чувствует: мне плохо
X думает: Y похож на Z
```

**Наглец**

Наглый

> на́глый прил., употр. сравн. часто Морфология: на́гл, нагла́, на́гло,
>   на́глы; нагле́е; нар. на́гло
>   1. Человека называют наглым, если он грубо и вызывающе ведёт себя, не уважает других людей; слово выражает осуждение. В молодости он был
>   чрезвычайно наглым и самоуверенным. | Он просто наглый шантажист.
>
> = нахальный
>   2. Слова, поступки и т. д. называют наглыми, если они дерзкие, вызывающие; слово выражает осуждение. Это был наглый обман. |
>
> нар. Ощущение безнаказанности во всём проникло и в сознание водителей,
>   многие начали нагло ездить на красный свет.
>
> 1. Взгляд, смех и т. д. называют наглыми, если в них проявляется дерзость, бесстыдство. Его наглый тон взбесил меня. |
>
> нар. Андрей оценивающе и нагло посмотрел на неё.
>
> • на́глость сущ., ж.
>
> Толковый словарь русского языка Дмитриева Д. В. Дмитриев. 2003

Здесь попробую сконцентрироваться на неуважении.

```
X думает: Y похож на кого-то
R - часть людей                      
Z делает или говорит что-то
из-за этого R потом думает: Z не думает и не чувствует, что я часть людей
из-за этого R потом чувствует: мне плохо
X думает: Y похож на Z
```

В переводе: R человек, а Z ведет себя так, как будто R не человек. И R это чувствует.

**Невоспитанный человек**

```
X думает: Y похож на кого-то
многие люди думают и знают : что-то (A) хорошо, что-то другое (B) - плохо
эти люди делают A и хотят не делать B
если кто-то делает B, потом все другие думают: 
этот кто-то многого не знает и из-за этого не может делать A
Z делает много B 
X думает: Y похож на Z
```

**Человек, способный на подлость**

```
X думает: Y похож на кого-то
многие люди думают и знают : что-то (A) хорошо, что-то другое (B) - очень плохо
эти люди хотят не делать B
если кто-то делает B, кому-то другому очень плохо
если кто-то делает B и знает: я делаю B, потом все другие думают: 
этот кто-то многого не чувствует, этот кто-то плохой
Z может сделать B
X думает: Y похож на Z
```

Конечно, я не учла множество аспектов вышеприведенных слов. Иначе, если бы я продолжила конкретизацию, то пришлось бы написать как минимум статью. По-моему, перевод слова на термины Вежбицкой очень похож на чтение толкового словаря, причем на языке, в котором знаешь только примитивы.

Осталось только применить конъюнкцию на все четыре определения, использовав разные переменные ( J,K,L,M, например ),  и перевести все с субъекта на его манеру поведения (или на поступок)

```
случилось что-то (G)                --Gадость =)
X думает: Y похож на кого-то
...описание J
...описание K
...описание L
...описание M
X думает: Y похож на J
X думает: Y похож на K
X думает: Y похож на L
X думает: Y похож на M
G случилось из-за Y                  -- хамство как поступок
Y делает много G                     -- хамство как черта хама
```

---

**EDIT (очень важно!)**

Только что вспомнила про одно эссе Сергея Довлатова: ["Это непереводимое слово "хамство""](http://www.sergeidovlatov.com/books/etoneper.html).

> И вот я долго думал над всем этим и, в отличие от Набокова,
>   сформулировал, что такое хамство, а именно: хамство есть не что иное,
>   как грубость, наглость, нахальство, вместе взятые, но при этом –
>   умноженные на безнаказанность. Именно в безнаказанности все дело, в
>   заведомом ощущении ненаказуемости, неподсудности деяний, в том чувстве
>   полнейшей беспомощности, которое охватывает жертву. Именно
>   безнаказанностью своей хамство и убивает вас наповал, вам нечего ему
>   противопоставить, кроме собственного унижения, потому что хамство –
>   это всегда «сверху вниз», это всегда «от сильного – слабому», потому
>   что хамство – это беспомощность одного и безнаказанность другого,
>   потому что хамство – это неравенство.

Думаю, в связи с этим нужно подкорректировать окончательный вариант определения.

```
случилось что-то (G)                --Gадость =)
X думает: Y похож на кого-то
...описание J
...описание K
...описание L
...описание M
X думает: Y похож на J
X думает: Y похож на K
X думает: Y похож на L
X думает: Y похож на M
Y знает:  с ним не случится плохого, если он сделает G
X чувствует: я маленький, а Y большой
X чувствует: я не могу, а Y может
G случилось из-за Y                  -- хамство как поступок
Y делает много G                     -- хамство как черта хама
```